# Apply function to a row in a data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

In base `R` I would do the following:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 4:1, c = 2:5)
apply(d, 1, which.max)
```

With `dplyr` I could do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate(u = purrr::pmap_int(list(a, b, c), function(...) which.max(c(...))))
```

If there’s another column in `d` I need to specify it, but I want this to work w/ an arbitrary amount if columns.

Conceptually, I’d like something like

```
pmap_int(list(everything()), ...)
pmap_int(list(.), ...)
```

But this does obviously not work. How would I solve that canonically with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just need the data to be specified as `.` as `data.frame` is a `list` with columns as list elements.  If we wrap `list(.)`, it becomes a nested list

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  mutate(u = pmap_int(., ~ which.max(c(...))))
#  a b c u
#1 1 4 2 2
#2 2 3 3 2
#3 3 2 4 3
#4 4 1 5 3
```

---

Or can use `cur_data()`

```
d %>%
   mutate(u = pmap_int(cur_data(), ~ which.max(c(...))))
```

---

Or if we want to use `everything()`, place that inside `select` as `list(everything())` doesn't address the data from which everything should be selected

```
d %>% 
   mutate(u = pmap_int(select(., everything()), ~ which.max(c(...))))
```

---

Or using `rowwise`

```
d %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(u = which.max(cur_data())) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      a     b     c     u
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     4     2     2
#2     2     3     3     2
#3     3     2     4     3
#4     4     1     5     3
```

---

Or this is more efficient with `max.col`

```
max.col(d, 'first')
#[1] 2 2 3 3
```

Or with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(d, which.max, MARGIN = 1)
#[1] 2 2 3 3
```

which can be included in `dplyr` as

```
d %>% 
    mutate(u = max.col(cur_data(), 'first'))
```

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried `pmap_int(., ...)`, but overall `cur_data()` is what I was eventually looking for (also for some other use cases). Thx!

Comment: @thothal the `...` will be within a lambda call

Comment: Thank you dear @akrun for this thorough explanation. I could've solved this but only in a single `pmap` form. Your valuable explanations just gave me so much insight in this kinda solutions. Thank you very much.

Comment: You almost covered everything and left no rooms to other answers :) Cool! +1

Comment: Haha, I forgot `data.table` here. Thanks for reminder! I added that :)

Comment: @akrun, of course. I was just to lazy to type the full function call, hence I abbreviated it to `(., ...)` being well aware that this is not the proper code ;)

Comment: Can you explain the `c(...)` ?

Comment: Is this equivalent to `d%>% mutate(u = pmap_int(., ~ which.max(.x)))` ?

Comment: Apprently the code above is not equivalent to your solution

Answer (score 2):

Here are some `data.table` options

```
setDT(d)[, u := which.max(unlist(.SD)), 1:nrow(d)]
```

or

```
setDT(d)[, u := max.col(.SD, "first")]
```