# Problem using rowwise() to count the number of NA's in each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowwise

I'm having trouble using rowwise() to count the number of NAs in each row. My minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(Q1 = c(rep(1, 1), rep(NA, 9)),
                 Q2 = c(rep(2, 2), rep(NA, 8)),
                 Q3 = c(rep(3, 3), rep(NA, 7))
)
df
   Q1 Q2 Q3
1   1  2  3
2  NA  2  3
3  NA NA  3
4  NA NA NA
5  NA NA NA
6  NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA
```

I would like to create a new column that counts the number of NAs in each row. I can do this very simply by writing

```
 df$Count_NA <- rowSums(is.na(df))
 df
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Count_NA
1   1  2  3        0
2  NA  2  3        1
3  NA NA  3        2
4  NA NA NA        3
5  NA NA NA        3
6  NA NA NA        3
7  NA NA NA        3
8  NA NA NA        3
9  NA NA NA        3
10 NA NA NA        3
```

But if I try and do this via dplyr using rowwise(), I get the wrong answer - the column Count_NA has the same number in each row:

```
df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
      Q1    Q2    Q3 Count_NA
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
 1     1     2     3       24
 2    NA     2     3       24
 3    NA    NA     3       24
 4    NA    NA    NA       24
 5    NA    NA    NA       24
 6    NA    NA    NA       24
 7    NA    NA    NA       24
 8    NA    NA    NA       24
 9    NA    NA    NA       24
10    NA    NA    NA       24
```

what am I doing wrong, and how do i fix this?

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count NAs per row in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801338/count-nas-per-row-in-dataframe)

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Understanding rowwise and c_across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282839/understanding-rowwise-and-c-across)

Answer (score 9):

Use `cur_data()` rather than dot.  `.[cur_group_id(), ]`, `c(Q1, Q2, Q3)`, `across()` or `c_across()` (or `c_across` with the argument as per other answer) would also work.

Note that it is best to use `ungroup` afterwards or else it will retain the memory of the rowwise and you might get unexpected results later on.

```
df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(cur_data()))) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
      Q1    Q2    Q3 Count_NA
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
 1     1     2     3        0
 2    NA     2     3        1
 3    NA    NA     3        2
 4    NA    NA    NA        3
 5    NA    NA    NA        3
 6    NA    NA    NA        3
 7    NA    NA    NA        3
 8    NA    NA    NA        3
 9    NA    NA    NA        3
10    NA    NA    NA        3
```

Comment: Grothendiek, FYI, [speed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151190/13513328)

Answer (score 6):

`rowSums` works directly with `mutate` without `rowwise`:

```
df %>% mutate(count_NA = rowSums(is.na(.)))

   Q1 Q2 Q3 count_NA
1   1  2  3        0
2  NA  2  3        1
3  NA NA  3        2
4  NA NA NA        3
5  NA NA NA        3
6  NA NA NA        3
7  NA NA NA        3
8  NA NA NA        3
9  NA NA NA        3
10 NA NA NA        3
```

Note that your initial solution is by far the fastest one:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df$Count_NA <- rowSums(is.na(df)),
  df$Count_NA <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))),
  df %>% mutate(count_NA = rowSums(is.na(.))),
  df %>%
    mutate(Count_NA = purrr::pmap(., ~ sum(is.na(c(...))))),
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(a=sum(is.na(c_across(everything())))),
  df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(cur_data()))) %>%
  ungroup
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                                            expr     min       lq
                                               df$Count_NA <- rowSums(is.na(df))    39.8    64.30
                          df$Count_NA <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))  1661.6  1868.40
                                     df %>% mutate(count_NA = rowSums(is.na(.)))  1181.7  1572.80
                   df %>% mutate(Count_NA = purrr::pmap(., ~sum(is.na(c(...)))))  4749.9  5190.35
             df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(a = sum(is.na(c_across(everything())))) 29124.1 31148.50
 df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(cur_data()))) %>%      ungroup 70473.0 73659.70
      mean   median       uq     max neval   cld
    79.033    76.25    88.75   174.0   100 a    
  2082.960  1966.50  2075.75  8777.3   100  b   
  1722.178  1676.20  1791.60  3112.9   100  b   
  5726.549  5396.40  5745.25 28592.1   100   c  
 33567.825 31983.05 33637.00 54676.9   100    d 
 77902.342 76492.85 81199.15 98942.1   100     e
Unit: microseconds
                                                                            expr     min       lq
                                               df$Count_NA <- rowSums(is.na(df))    38.2    44.95
                          df$Count_NA <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))  1584.8  1765.30
                                     df %>% mutate(count_NA = rowSums(is.na(.)))  1247.9  1496.95
                   df %>% mutate(Count_NA = purrr::pmap(., ~sum(is.na(c(...)))))  4614.0  5110.50
 df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Count_NA = sum(is.na(cur_data()))) %>%      ungroup 67413.5 70865.45
      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    71.159    65.85    84.40    162.2   100 a  
  1967.629  1894.45  2093.30   3436.6   100 ab 
  1814.193  1666.25  1895.35   9031.0   100 a  
  5796.483  5380.70  5665.10  15309.7   100  b 
 78309.807 75275.30 79776.40 286964.3   100   c
```

Comment: I think I'm most surprised by how inefficient `cur_data()` is.

Comment: I started out asking this question because I had the rowSums and the apply() solutions working well, and was trying to move my solution from base R to dplyr. Now that I see your speed comparisons, i'm sticking with base R! That said, I have learned a lot from this discussion. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5):

One issue is that `.` here resolves to the whole frame, not just the whole row.
Another dplyr method, using `c_across`:

```r
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(a=sum(is.na(c_across(everything()))))
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Rowwise: 
#       Q1    Q2    Q3     a
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1     1     2     3     0
#  2    NA     2     3     1
#  3    NA    NA     3     2
#  4    NA    NA    NA     3
#  5    NA    NA    NA     3
#  6    NA    NA    NA     3
#  7    NA    NA    NA     3
#  8    NA    NA    NA     3
#  9    NA    NA    NA     3
# 10    NA    NA    NA     3
```

The biggest difference I can see between using this and `cur_data()` is that `c_across` allows for variable-selection a little more directly, as in `c_across(starts_with("Q"))`. Granted, one could always `select(cur_data(),...)`, so this is a weak argument.

Comment: Thanks - how does one determine what the . resolves to?

Comment: Frankly, I did `func <- function(z, ...) {browser();0;}` and then `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Count_NA = func(.))`, then looked at `z` to see. It doesn't help resolve the issue, just to identify it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck's answer is canonical in the sense that that answer uses `cur_data()`. This answer is canonical in that it uses `c_across`. Pick and choose. I tend to believe `c_across` was meant for this type of thing, but I'm sure there are counter-examples as well.

Comment: @r2evans, FYI, [speed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151190/13513328)

Comment: @Waldi, I didn't say I *like* `c_across`, just that it's canonically what (I think) is the recommendation for tasks like this. I really tend to avoid row-wise operations in `dplyr` verbs: most of my data tends to have 100K or more rows, so I have been conditioned to avoid it :-)

Comment: @r2evans, I actually like your answer, but I was surprised by the speed comparison. I also work with >100k tables, and left `dplyr` for `data.table`.

Answer (score 5):

baseR answer

```
df$Count_NA <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))                 

df
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Count_NA
1   1  2  3        0
2  NA  2  3        1
3  NA NA  3        2
4  NA NA NA        3
5  NA NA NA        3
6  NA NA NA        3
7  NA NA NA        3
8  NA NA NA        3
9  NA NA NA        3
10 NA NA NA        3
```

So can be integrated into dplyr pipe

```
df %>% mutate(count_NA = apply(., 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))

   Q1 Q2 Q3 count_NA
1   1  2  3        0
2  NA  2  3        1
3  NA NA  3        2
4  NA NA NA        3
5  NA NA NA        3
6  NA NA NA        3
7  NA NA NA        3
8  NA NA NA        3
9  NA NA NA        3
10 NA NA NA        3
```

Comment: FYI, [speed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151190/13513328)

Comment: Thanks for tagging me in.  Great info.  TFS

Answer (score 4):

In case future you were interested in a row-wise solution with `purrr` package functions:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Count_NA = pmap(., ~ sum(is.na(c(...)))))


   Q1 Q2 Q3 Count_NA
1   1  2  3        0
2  NA  2  3        1
3  NA NA  3        2
4  NA NA NA        3
5  NA NA NA        3
6  NA NA NA        3
7  NA NA NA        3
8  NA NA NA        3
9  NA NA NA        3
10 NA NA NA        3
```

Comment: You can use `pmap` for much more complex row-wise operations with multiple variables:
in case you were interested you can check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935005/apply-function-to-a-row-in-a-data-frame-using-dplyr

Comment: FYI, [speed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151190/13513328)

Comment: @Waldi oh it's an interesting comparison. But I normally prefer to use `pmap` for more complex row-wise operations. It's no denying that `rowSums` is more simple and by far the fastest.

Comment: I like your solution and I'm also a fond user of `purrr`, but `microbenchmark` is always useful to find the most efficient way.

Comment: @Waldi Thank you very much. You are right. Since it's barely a year I started learning R, I put more emphasis on first getting the desired output & then trying alternative solutions. However in this case I was trying to propose a solution different than those already posted. It's also interesting there is a package called `bench` that does the same as `microbenchmark` & I don't yet know how it differs from the latter one.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dapply`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)), MARGIN = 1)
#[1] 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, however, an alternate way to address your problem where, for example, you needed to calculate NAs over different sets of columns would be like this:

```
# You can specify different column sets
cols_to_check1 <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
cols_to_check2 <- c("Q1", "Q2")
```

Then, you apply the `rowSums` function with `mutate()`

```
df %>%
 mutate(count_NA1 = rowSums(across(cols_to_check1, ~ is.na(.))),
        count_NA2 = rowSums(across(cols_to_check2, ~ is.na(.))))
```

The solution for this would be as below:

```
   Q1 Q2 Q3 count_NA1  count_NA2
1   1  2  3        0           0
2  NA  2  3        1           1
3  NA NA  3        2           2
4  NA NA NA        3           2
5  NA NA NA        3           2
6  NA NA NA        3           2
7  NA NA NA        3           2
8  NA NA NA        3           2
9  NA NA NA        3           2
10 NA NA NA        3           2
```